# I need to Parse a JSON file and show its data on my web page locally

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I'm trying to fetch my JSON file using ajax request and its not loading,all i want is to show some specific data contained in the json file by using some variable which will contain the parsed data and it's output will get displayed on the web Page in browsers. But When I'm running it shows only the html elements which i've created and in debugger i came to know that the code after the click function is not executing it all.The code which i'm using is as:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Reading Json Data from Json File</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>

        //When DOM loaded we attach click event to button
        $(document).ready(function () {

            //after button is clicked we download the data
            $('.button').click(function () {
                debugger;
                //start ajax request
                $.ajax({
                    url: "data.json",
                    //force to handle it as text
                    dataType: "text",
                    success: function (data) {

                        //data downloaded so we call parseJSON function
                        //and pass downloaded data
                        var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                        //now json variable contains data in json format
                        //let's display a few items
                        $('#results').html('Plugin name: ' + json.name + '<br />Author: ' + json.author.name);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
         .button{
            margin:20px;
            font-size:16px;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding:5px 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="Json file/data.json" target="_blank">Open Json File</a><br />
    <input type="button" value="Get and Parse JSON" class="button" /><br />
    <span id="results"></span>

</body>
</html>
Besides My JSON file named"Data" contains:

    {
    "name": "select2",
    "title": "Select2",
    "description": "Select2 is a jQuery based replacement for select boxes. It supports searching, remote data sets, and infinite scrolling of results.",
    "keywords": [
        "select",
        "autocomplete",
        "typeahead",
        "dropdown",
        "multiselect",
        "tag",
        "tagging"
    ],
    "version": "3.4.2",
    "author": {
        "name": "Igor Vaynberg",
        "url": "https://github.com/ivaynberg"
    },
    "licenses": [
        {
            "type": "Apache",
            "url": "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0"
        },
        {
            "type": "GPL v2",
            "url": "http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html"
        }
    ],
    "bugs": "https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues",
    "homepage": "http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2",
    "docs": "http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/",
    "download": "https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/tags",
    "dependencies": {
        "jquery": ">=1.7.1"
    }
}
```

and i've loaded this file into folder in the project's explorer.

Comment: did you print `console.log(data)` ?

Comment: It's showing error 404:Resource file not found,it's not able to find my json file at all

Answer (score 0):

$.parseJSON(data)  could return an array Try accessing by index

```
json[0].name
```

then

```
$('#results').html('Plugin name: ' +  json[0].name +
                       '<br />Author: ' +  json[0].author.name);
```

Comment: the json file is not found sir @scaisEdge your suggestion is too far!

Answer (score 0):

Above code not work in chrome because it won't allow cross-origin request. To avoid this you can run the code inside web server. Ajax URL request without web server won't work in chrome. Check with firefox that will work. So better run your application(html+data) inside web server. please check the code below

```js
//When DOM loaded we attach click event to button
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //after button is clicked we download the data
            $('.button').click(function () {
                debugger;
                //start ajax request
                $.ajax({
                    url: "data.json",
                    //force to handle it as text
                    dataType: "text",
                    success: function (data) {

                        //data downloaded so we call parseJSON function
                        //and pass downloaded data
                        var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                        //now json variable contains data in json format
                        //let's display a few items
                        $('#results').html('Plugin name: ' + json.name + '<br />Author: ' + json.author.name);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

```css
.button{
            margin:20px;
            font-size:16px;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding:5px 10px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Reading Json Data from Json File</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="data.json" target="_blank">Open Json File</a><br />
    <input type="button" value="Get and Parse JSON" class="button" /><br />
    <span id="results"></span>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried it inside webservers? Keep index.html file and data.json file in the same folder and try to open line http://localhost:8080/JSONload/  this will work i tried it inside server its working

Comment: But how do i host one?

Comment: If u wanna check , comment the url in ajax and keep the json data inside the success function

Comment: still i'm stuck